# HTML - Why am I not able to type into this HTML text area?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I have a text area:

```
<textarea name="p_comments" rows="5" cols="39" align="left" wrap="cwrap" onfocus="this.blur()">
```

When I go to type into this box, it does nothing. there is a text box right next to it that works but it does not have the `onfocus="this.blur()"` is this the culprit?

I attempted to remove this in the source editor, however, I am still unable to type into the box. I cannot change the HTML on the server so I wanted to see if the "blur" is the cause or maybe the css?

css:

```
element.style {
}
textarea[Attributes Style] {
    text-align: left;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
textarea {
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input:not([type="image" i]), textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea {
    font-family: monospace;
    border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
}
textarea {
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    background-color: white;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    flex-direction: column;
    resize: auto;
    cursor: auto;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
input, textarea, keygen, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
}
input, textarea, keygen, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
Inherited from td
TD {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 10pt;
}
Inherited from table
table {
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: medium;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: -internal-quirk-inherit;
    text-align: start;
}
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}
Inherited from td
TD {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 10pt;
}
Inherited from table
table {
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: medium;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: -internal-quirk-inherit;
    text-align: start;
}
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}



﻿
﻿
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onfocus="this.blur()"
```

Yes, that's where the problem comes from. If you remove this from devtool, it won't change anything because the JavaScript is already executed when you try too.

The solution would be to remove this event listener (I can't really see how knowing you need a function name - wich you have not), or replacing the element with an other textarea using JavaScript. (That's kinda ugly to do, though)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense as to why it didn't change. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`onfocus="this.blur()"` is definitely the culprit. It's trying to make the text area read only.

Answer (score 0):

remove onfocus="this.blur()" from textarea

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can use this script to `force` it focus the `textarea`:

```
var allEle = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for(i=0; i<allEle.length; i++){
    var ele = allEle.item(i);
  focueEle(ele)
}

function focueEle(ele){
    ele.onfocus = function() {
        ele.focus();
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b6pshw0m/2/